# PHP In an Option Tag

Tags: php

Firstly apologies for asking this as it is quite basic but
I just can't seem to get it right. Have searched on here and
elsewhere for an answer (and tried various) but there is always
an error. Spent too long on this little bit and should really know
the answer but here goes:

Ok I have a main php file using an include statement to bring in a drop down menu
with the options being populated from a MySQL database. In the file being included I have this while loop which creates the
options and works fine:

```
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ManList2 = $db_field['categoryName']; 
    echo '<option value="' . $ManList2 . '">' . $ManList2 . '</option>';
}
```

What I want to add is something like the following in the option tag:

```
if($search == '$ManList2') { echo 'selected'; }
```

I just can't seem to get it right in the echo statement.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `if($search == $ManList2)` or even `if($search == "$ManList2")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo '<option value="'.$ManList2.'" '.($search == $ManList2 ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$ManList2.'</option>';
```

Comment: Thanks Paul and to everyone - didn't really want to ask as I like to work things out for myself but just couldn't get it right. Think it was the echoing of the html and the position ' " . etc    Yours was the second one I tried and works great so thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ManList2 = $db_field['categoryName'];

    echo '<option value="' . $ManList2 . '"';

    if($search == '$ManList2') {
        echo ' selected';
    }

    echo '>' . $ManList2 . '</option>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option value='".$ManList2; if($search == '$ManList2'){ echo 'selected'; } echo "'>".$ManList2."</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this (Assumed your select's name is `search`)

```
$search = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : ''; // or $_GET maybe
$selected = '';
while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    $ManList2 = $db_field['categoryName']; 
    $selected = $search == $ManList2 ? 'selected' : '';
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$ManList2.'">'.$ManList2.'</option>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use variables to put into your PHP, like:

```
while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $ManList2 = $db_field['categoryName']; 
  $selected = $search === $ManList2 ? "selected='selected'" : '';
  echo "<option value='$ManList2'$selected>$ManList2</option>"; 
}
```

I don't see what `$search` does, so this approach may not work. I would use my **[PHPglue](https://www.phpglue.com)** Library. It handles this sort of thing for you.